# How to install tensorflow for Django Applications

Tags: django, tensorflow

I am trying to use tensorflow for my django web application. I installed tensor flow in anaconda using the following commands

```
conda create -n tensorflow_env tensorflow
conda activate tensorflow_env
```

Now I am trying to import tensor flow and executing the below script in django shell but I am getting an error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

I have read similar questions but they talk about the tensorflow environment is different from the conda environment. How do I make sure that the tensorflow imports work in my anaconda environment. I am pretty confused about these environments.

Here is my code

```
from django.db.models import Avg,Sum
from django.db.models.functions import TruncDate

import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create your views here.

from myapp.models import Order



orders = Order.objects.all().annotate(date = TruncDate('timestamp')).values('itemName','date').annotate(itemPrice = Avg('itemPrice'),quantity=Sum('quantity'),orderPrice = Sum('orderPrice'))
df = pd.DataFrame(list(orders))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used

```
conda install tensorflow
```

instead of

```
conda create -n tensorflow_env tensorflow
conda activate tensorflow_env
```

The above lines create a new environment tensorflow_env

Answer (score 1):

[Installing via `pip`](https://www.tensorflow.org/install) should be enough:

```
pip install tensorflow
```

or you can check the version of your python on it is 32 bit or 64 bit